# Merge two array into String

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two array. I want them to merge and display as a string. I have tried but I doesn't came as per requirement.

**Code**

```
a = [age,weight];
b = [25,77];

var a1 = a.toString();
var b1 = b.toString();
var result = `${a1} : ${b1}`;
```

**Output**

```
age, weight : 25,77
```

Expected Output

```
age :25 , weight:77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take keys and values in an array and reduce the data by building pairs.

```js
var keys = ['age', 'weight'],
    values = [25, 77],
    result = [keys, values]
        .reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => `${v}: ${b[i]}`))
        .join(', ');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `join` will simplify.

```js
const a = ["age", "weight"];
const b = [25, 77];

const res = a.map((key, i) => `${key}: ${b[i]}`).join(", ");

console.log(res);
```